# How can I do a regular expression loop?

Tags: r, regex, loops

So my situation is that I have a list of files in a physical chemistry dataset which I created from multiple calculations, and I want run a foreach or while loop through a column named Files in my dataframe titled, CD1_and_CH2_INTERACTION_ENERGIES_and_DISTANCES.

I have filenames which look like this: "1AH7A_TRP-16-A_GLU-9-A.log:", "1AH7A_TRP-198-A_ASP-197-A.log:", "1BGFA_TRP-43-A_GLU-44-A.log:", "1CXQA_TRP-61-A_ASP-82-A.log:", etc ...

I want to run a while or foreach loop through my column "Files", and if exists the word "GLU" or "ASP", and then if I find "GLU" or "ASP", in the file I want to print it to a list.

So in the files above, the printing order would be "GLU", "ASP", "GLU", "ASP". Again, my files aren't order in any particular way, and all the way down through my 1273 entries of files. Then I can save this list and put it into a column title "Residues" in my dataframe, and do some useful exploratory data analysis.

Note: ASP is for the amino acid Aspartate, and GLU is for the amino acid Glutamate.

---

I know that I can regular expression search grep for the terms in a the column "Files" like so.

Searching for "ASP":

```
> grep("ASP", CD1_and_CH2_INTERACTION_ENERGIES_and_DISTANCES$Files, value = TRUE)

[1] "1AH7A_TRP-198-A_ASP-197-A.log:"  
[2] "1CXQA_TRP-61-A_ASP-82-A.log:"    
[3] "1EJDA_TRP-279-A_ASP-278-A.log:"  
[4] "1EU1A_TRP-32-A_ASP-33-A.log:"
```

As you can see I get a few matches. In fact I get 683 matches. But that's not good enough. I need the matches where they occur, not that they occur.

And of course I can grep for "GLU":

```
> grep("GLU", CD1_and_CH2_INTERACTION_ENERGIES_and_DISTANCES$Files, value = TRUE)

[1] "1AH7A_TRP-16-A_GLU-9-A.log:"     
[2] "1BGFA_TRP-43-A_GLU-44-A.log:"    
[3] "1D8WA_TRP-17-A_GLU-14-A.log:"
```

And I get a whole bunch of matches!

I tried a for loop. Of course it failed!!!

```
  > for(i in 1:length(CD1_and_CH2_Distances$Distance_Files))
{if(grep("ASP", CD1_and_CH2_INTERACTION_ENERGIES_and_DISTANCES$Files))

{print("ASP")} 

else if(grep("GLU", CD1_and_CH2_INTERACTION_ENERGIES_and_DISTANCES$Files))

{print("GLU")}}
```

All it did was print:

```
[1] "ASP"

[1] "ASP"

[1] "ASP"

...
```

Even though there is "GLU"!

I mean I can do basic algebraic loops that don't matter to anyone:

```
> for(i in 1:10){print(i^2)}
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 9
[1] 16
```

Anyway, I checked the warnings to see what was going wrong:

```
> warnings() 
Warning messages: 

1: In if (grep("ASP", CD1_and_CH2_INTERACTION_ENERGIES_and_DISTANCES$Files)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (grep("ASP", CD1_and_CH2_INTERACTION_ENERGIES_and_DISTANCES$Files)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

As you can see I'm getting the same error over and over again. I guess that makes sense since this is a a loop. But why is this happening, and why can't I grep inside of a loop?

---

My dataframe that I am trying to parse looks like this:

```
"","Files","Interaction_Energy_kcal_per_Mole","atom","Distance_Angstroms"
"1","1AH7A_TRP-16-A_GLU-9-A.log:",-8.49787784468197,"CD1",4.03269909613896
"2","1AH7A_TRP-198-A_ASP-197-A.log:",-7.92648167142146,"CD1",3.54307493570204
"3","1BGFA_TRP-43-A_GLU-44-A.log:",-6.73507800775909,"CD1",4.17179517713897
"4","1CXQA_TRP-61-A_ASP-82-A.log:",-9.39887176290279,"CD1",5.29897291934956
"5","1D8WA_TRP-17-A_GLU-14-A.log:",-9.74720319145055,"CD1",3.69398565238145
"6","1D8WA_TRP-17-A_GLU-18-A.log:",-11.3235196065977,"CD1",3.52345441293058
"7","1DJ0A_TRP-223-A_GLU-226-A.log:",-7.46891330209553,"CD1",5.41108436452436
"8","1E58A_TRP-15-A_GLU-18-A.log:",-6.59830781067777,"CD1",4.79790235415437
```

where commas separate columns.

This is what I want the result to look like:

```
"","Files","Interaction_Energy_kcal_per_Mole","atom","Distance_Angstroms", "Residue",

    "1","1AH7A_TRP-16-A_GLU-9-A.log:",-8.49787784468197,"CD1",4.03269909613896, "GLU",

    "2","1AH7A_TRP-198-A_ASP-197-A.log:",-7.92648167142146,"CD1",3.54307493570204, "ASP",

    "3","1BGFA_TRP-43-A_GLU-44-A.log:",-6.73507800775909,"CD1",4.17179517713897, "GLU",

    "4","1CXQA_TRP-61-A_ASP-82-A.log:",-9.39887176290279,"CD1",5.29897291934956, "ASP",

    "5","1D8WA_TRP-17-A_GLU-14-A.log:",-9.74720319145055,"CD1",3.69398565238145, "GLU",

    "6","1D8WA_TRP-17-A_GLU-18-A.log:",-11.3235196065977,"CD1",3.52345441293058, "GLU",

    "7","1DJ0A_TRP-223-A_GLU-226-A.log:",-7.46891330209553,"CD1",5.41108436452436, "GLU",

    "8","1E58A_TRP-15-A_GLU-18-A.log:",-6.59830781067777,"CD1",4.79790235415437, "GLU",

...
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I get your question completely but consider your data resides in "dat" data(which contains rows for GLU and ASP). Use below to tabulate a field which can contain the data of "ASP" and "GLU".

```
library(stringr)
    newvar <- NULL
    newvar$GLU <- str_extract(dat$Files,"(GLU)")
    newvar$ASP <- str_extract(dat$Files,"(ASP)")
    newvar1 <- data.frame(newvar)
    newvar1
    library(tidyr)
    newvar1[is.na(newvar1)] = ""
    new <- unite(newvar1, new, GLU:ASP, sep='')
    dat$new <- new
```

Here the field called new would contain your value of GLU and ASP

**Answer:**

```
    dat
  X                          Files Interaction_Energy_kcal_per_Mole atom Distance_Angstroms new
1 1    1AH7A_TRP-16-A_GLU-9-A.log:                        -8.497878  CD1           4.032699 GLU
2 2 1AH7A_TRP-198-A_ASP-197-A.log:                        -7.926482  CD1           3.543075 ASP
3 3   1BGFA_TRP-43-A_GLU-44-A.log:                        -6.735078  CD1           4.171795 GLU
4 4   1CXQA_TRP-61-A_ASP-82-A.log:                        -9.398872  CD1           5.298973 ASP
5 5   1D8WA_TRP-17-A_GLU-14-A.log:                        -9.747203  CD1           3.693986 GLU
6 6   1D8WA_TRP-17-A_GLU-18-A.log:                       -11.323520  CD1           3.523454 GLU
7 7 1DJ0A_TRP-223-A_GLU-226-A.log:                        -7.468913  CD1           5.411084 GLU
8 8   1E58A_TRP-15-A_GLU-18-A.log:                        -6.598308  CD1           4.797902 GLU
```

Comment: Everything works, except I get GLUNA and NAASP because your command to remove the NA's didn't work for me. I didn't know str_extract existed.

Comment: It should work, you have to replace NA, using "" like i did it, newvar1[is.na(newvar1)] = "" , This should work along with unite, map libraries stringr and tidyr. In case you are happy with solution please accept the solution

Answer (score 2):

We can use `split` the dataset into a `list` of `data.frame` using substring derived with `sub`

```
lst <- split(df1, sub(".*_([A-Z]{3})-.*", "\\1", df1$Files))
```

#### data

```
  df1 <- structure(list(X = 1:8, Files = c("1AH7A_TRP-16-A_GLU-9-A.log:", 
"1AH7A_TRP-198-A_ASP-197-A.log:", "1BGFA_TRP-43-A_GLU-44-A.log:", 
"1CXQA_TRP-61-A_ASP-82-A.log:", "1D8WA_TRP-17-A_GLU-14-A.log:", 
"1D8WA_TRP-17-A_GLU-18-A.log:", "1DJ0A_TRP-223-A_GLU-226-A.log:", 
"1E58A_TRP-15-A_GLU-18-A.log:"), Interaction_Energy_kcal_per_Mole = c(-8.49787784468197, 
-7.92648167142146, -6.73507800775909, -9.39887176290279, -9.74720319145055, 
-11.3235196065977, -7.46891330209553, -6.59830781067777), atom = c("CD1", 
"CD1", "CD1", "CD1", "CD1", "CD1", "CD1", "CD1"), Distance_Angstroms = c(4.03269909613896, 
3.54307493570204, 4.17179517713897, 5.29897291934956, 3.69398565238145, 
3.52345441293058, 5.41108436452436, 4.79790235415437)), .Names = c("X", 
"Files", "Interaction_Energy_kcal_per_Mole", "atom", "Distance_Angstroms"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

After a long time I figured out a solution to my problem:

# Save my column as a vector because factors are making the world burn:

```
Files <- as.vector(CD1_and_CH2_INTERACTION_ENERGIES_and_DISTANCES$Files)
```

# Split the Files into three parts along the two underscores, and save it back to my vector, preserving the third cut around the underscore.

```
Files <- str_split_fixed(Files, "_", 3)[,3]
```

Result:

[1] "GLU-9-A.log:"
  "ASP-197-A.log:"
etc ...

# Split those results along the hyphens, and take what's next to the first hyphen or the first cut:

```
Residues <- str_split_fixed(Files, "-", 3)[,1]

> Residues
   [1] "GLU" "ASP" "GLU", ...
```

Add the Residue columns to my data.frame.

```
CD1_and_CH2_INTERACTION_ENERGIES_and_DISTANCES$Residue <- Residue
```

I guess the grep function is overrated. I had to look hard for this function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you saved the data you are trying to parse in the file `glu_vs_asp.csv`.

Below is an example of how you can create two data frames, one for GLU and one for ASP:

```
# Read .csv file.
dt <- read.table(file = "glu_vs_asp.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)

# Create two data frames, one for GLU and one for ASP.
dt_glu <- dt[grep("GLU", dt$Files),]

dt_asp <- dt[grep("ASP", dt$Files),]
```

To create a data frame containing both GLU and ASP you can try the following:

```
dt_glu_asp <- dt[grep("(ASP|GLU)", dt$Files),]
```

The commands

```
grep("ASP", dt$Files)
grep("GLU", dt$Files)
```

give you the indices of the rows that contain respectively 'ASP' and 'GLU' in the `Files` column.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't want to know how many GLU or ASP there are. I want to know print there exact positions. If I create two dataframes and then rbind them they will not be in the proper order with Respect to the column files.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The data is still associated with the respective file, since we are just creating subsets of the main data frame. I'll add a way to retrieve the row indices if that helps.

Comment: I think row indices is what I mean.

Comment: In that case you may want to read up on the function `grep` and its parameter `value`. You were very close.

Comment: Wow! This is such a puzzle. Your tip to create a dataframe containing both ASP or GLU just gives me back my original dataframe as a new dataframe. It only detected that ASP and GLU was present in every filename, so it just gave me everything that I had to begin with back.

Comment: I just want a file by file match of (ASP|GLU) in all of my files.

Comment: Starting from the example data at the end of your post, create an example of what the result should look like. Then we can better help you.